# How can I normalize the numerical variables in a dataset?

Tags: python, normalization

How can I normalize a dataset?

The dataset is composed by int and float (they have also negative values), there are something like 36 columns (variables) with different distributions.

I want to transform them in order to have a normal distribution for the application of a regression model.

I tried `box-cox` and `yeo-jansen` but in the first case I have problem with negative values, while in the second case I have this error:

```
"RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log".
```

Comment: Did you try [Numpy](https://numpy.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sklearn.preprocessing`. Link to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html)